# kdb - How can I recursively update rows in a table?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of tick data

``````
q)t:([]symbol:8#`ABC;receiverIMID:`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2;ID:`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018;priorID:`````2018`2017`2018`2017;date:8#.z.Z;priorDate:(0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;.z.Z;.z.Z-1;.z.Z;.z.Z-1);status:8#1)
q)t
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.06.30T18:33:18.039                         1
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.06.30T18:33:18.039                         1
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.06.30T18:33:18.039                         1
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.06.30T18:33:18.039                         1
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 1
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 2020.06.29T18:33:18.039 1
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 1
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.06.30T18:33:18.039 2020.06.29T18:33:18.039 1
``````

and a table of historic data

```
q)t2:([]SYM:2#`ABC;IMID:`rep1`rep2;ID:2#`2017;DATE:2#.z.Z-1;PS:15)
q)t2
SYM IMID ID   DATE                    PS
----------------------------------------
ABC rep1 2017 2020.06.29T18:36:48.905 15
ABC rep2 2017 2020.06.29T18:36:48.905 15
```

I update the status of table `t` with the PS from table `t2` if the `SYM, IMID, ID` match the `symbol, recieverIMID, ID (or) priorID` from table `t`...

```
tt:select OID:{$[null x;y;x]}'[priorID;ID],symbol, receiverIMID, status from t
th:select ID,SYM,IMID,PS from t2
update status:(exec status from (tt lj 3!cols[tt] xcol th)) from `t
```

which makes the following updates to table `t`

```
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 1
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 1
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
```

Then I'd like to exec the `ID` of the row that was just updated, update all rows from table `t` with that `ID`, and check if that `ID` is in `priorID`, e.g., after updating where `priorID` in 2017 then update the other rows where `ID` in 2018, and check if 2018 is in `priorID`. It would look like the following...

```
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         1
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 1
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 1
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
```

I'll repeat this process, updating all rows where `ID` is present and checking to see if `ID` is in `priorID`. In this case 2019 is not in `priorID` so we'll exit the function. Final update table would look like the following...

```
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.06.30T00:00:00.000                         15
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 15
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 15
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.06.30T00:00:00.000 2020.06.29T00:00:00.000 15
```

I'm assuming we would want to use `over` (/) for the recursion, though I'm not sure how to properly implement the recursive lookup and updates. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be mis-interpreting but this looks like a parent-child ID setup, which I would tackle as having a map of parents to children and then follow that map all the way through recursively to its lowest child - and then join that child info. (I think you're doing the same but in reverse?). It's hard to know exactly from your sample. Either way, this might give you an idea:

``````
q)t:([]symbol:8#`ABC;receiverIMID:`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2;ID:`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018;priorID:`````2018`2017`2018`2017;date:8#.z.Z;priorDate:(0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;.z.Z;.z.Z-1;.z.Z;.z.Z-1);status:8#1);
q)t2:([]SYM:2#`ABC;IMID:`rep1`rep2;ID:2#`2017;DATE:2#.z.Z-1;PS:15);
q)childMap:exec ID!priorID from t where not null priorID; /might want to make this unique
q)(update child:.Q.fu[{x^childMap x}/;ID] from t) lj 3!select symbol:SYM,receiverIMID:IMID,child:ID,status:PS from t2
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status child
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.07.01T03:54:44.235                         15     2017
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.07.01T03:54:44.235                         15     2017
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.07.01T03:54:44.235                         15     2017
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.07.01T03:54:44.235                         15     2017
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 15     2017
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 2020.06.30T03:54:44.235 15     2017
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 15     2017
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.07.01T03:54:44.235 2020.06.30T03:54:44.235 15     2017
``````

Comment: Thank you, Terry. Yes, parent-child ID is the set-up. This appears to work. Now I need to read up on .Q.fu (apply unique) so I can understand that part of the code more intuitively.

Comment: Great! If it makes it easier to follow, the .Q.fu part can be replaced with `update child:({x^childMap x}/)each ID from t` or to make it even more explicit you can use scan to show all intermediary children: `update child:({x^childMap x}\)each ID from t`.  I only used .Q.fu as it looked like you had a lot of repetitive values and each one would follow the same parent-child path so instead of doing the same operation many time, .Q.fu will just do the unique ones and copy for the rest

Answer (score 2):

The below function will recursively edit the rows of the table as required:

```
func:{
 tt:select OID:{$[null x;y;x]}'[priorID;ID],symbol, receiverIMID, status from t; 
 $[x[0]=0; 
  th:select ID,SYM,IMID,PS from t2; 
  th: select ID,symbol,receiverIMID,status from t where ID in x[2]
  ]; 
 changedrowpriorids: exec OID from (tt ij 3!cols[tt] xcol th); 
 changedrowids: exec ID from t where priorID in changedrowpriorids; 
 update status:(exec status from (tt lj 3!cols[tt] xcol th)) from `t; 
 update status: first (exec distinct status from t where priorID in changedrowpriorids) from `t where ID in changedrowids; 
 (1; not (`$()) ~ exec ID from t where priorID in changedrowids;changedrowids) 
 }
```

So:

``````
q)t:([]symbol:8#`ABC;receiverIMID:`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2`rep1`rep1`rep2`rep2;ID:`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018`2019`2018;priorID:`````2018`2017`2018`2017;date:8#.z.Z;priorDate:(0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;0Nz;.z.Z;.z.Z-1;.z.Z;.z.Z-1);status:8#1)
q)t2:([]SYM:2#`ABC;IMID:`rep1`rep2;ID:2#`2017;DATE:2#.z.Z-1;PS:15)
q)\c 200 200
q)t
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         1
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         1
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         1
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         1
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 1
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.06.30T11:49:39.108 1
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 1
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.06.30T11:49:39.108 1
q)func\[{x[1]=1b};(0;1b;`)]
0 1b `
1 1b `2018`2018
1 0b `2019`2019
q)t
symbol receiverIMID ID   priorID date                    priorDate               status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC    rep1         2019         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         15
ABC    rep1         2018         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         15
ABC    rep2         2019         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         15
ABC    rep2         2018         2020.07.01T11:49:39.108                         15
ABC    rep1         2019 2018    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 15
ABC    rep1         2018 2017    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.06.30T11:49:39.108 15
ABC    rep2         2019 2018    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 15
ABC    rep2         2018 2017    2020.07.01T11:49:39.108 2020.06.30T11:49:39.108 15
``````